# IOS:CS193p fall2013 assignment2 task2:add a button to let user to restart the game

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, cs193p

I am learning the course CS193P(IOS develop) on itunes and I just started assignment2. I got stuck on the task that asks me to restart the game.
  A little bit background on the project: I am writing code for the newly added action method for the restart button in my CardGameViewController. I have two private properties: **game** and **deck**. I use lazy initialization in the CardGameViewController to initialize them when user first touch a button(flip a card).(The original project that the professor went over in the lecture is just some cards on the UI and user can flip them around and match them,without the restart function, which is the one I am asked to add in the homework.)
  In order for the user to restart the game, I think I need to reinitialize the two properties I mentioned above and update the UI. I tried the following code but the program crashed when I touch the button I just added:

```
- (IBAction)touchRestartButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    self.game = nil;
    self.theDeck = nil;
    // Maybe I also need to initialize the two properties again here using some code which I cannot figure out right now.... 
    [self updateUI];
}
```

Can anyone explain to me how to reinitialize a property in objective-c?(I also tried [self.game release], but the complier prevented me to do this because it says it is in ARC mode)
  Or is there any other way to finish this restarting game task?

Comment: I don't know what your classes are but you would call the designated initialiser on both your game and deck; as an example: `self.game = [[Game alloc] init]; self.theDeck = [Deck alloc] initWithCards:52];`. You would need to show your `Game` and `Deck` headers for us to write the exact code.

Comment: I know how to call my initialize method for both of my properties; but I don't know how to "clear" my properties and re initialize them again...

Comment: Do you mean the self.property = nil is correct?? Or do you mean that I don't need to "clear" them that I just initialize and alloc them again then the original memory for the property will be automatically released?

Comment: When you "clear" your properties you can either set them to nil or reassign them new objects. In either case, the previous objects will be released (provided no other strong references to them exist) and the memory will be released. In your case, you need to assign new objects using `alloc/init` (using one of your class designated initializers) so that you can reset the game to a fresh starting state.

Comment: I added the code into the buttonTouch method to initialize the two properties again(just call alloc and their designated initialization method) but I got the error as following:“unrecognized selector sent to instance ”..

Comment: You are trying to send a message (call a method) to an object of the wrong type. Create a new question with the exact error message and any class headers relevant to the objects involved.

Comment: Here is the new question I created with more specific description of my problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966954/objective-c-property-reinitialization, you can take a look at it if you have time and I would really appreciate it! BTW: thanks for the help so far!

Comment: I figured out the problem...it is pretty simple though,it is not the error of my code, it is because I accidentally deleted the first version of code(the block of code of my touchButton method) that was generated when I connected the button on the UI(storyBoard)(when I hold on "alt" button on my keyboard and draw the line to my controller to generate the code ) to my code. The solution is: delete the original button on the storyBoard and regenerate the code(the method) for the button.... Seems like I cannot generate code for the same button on the UI for more than once, otherwise it will

Comment: cause the problem I got...seems like the button is still looking for the original method I have already deleted(even though it is exactly the same as the one I connected and generated later)...I think that is why “unrecognized selector sent to instance ” happened... but it is still weird..