# Objective-c property reinitialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I am creating this question to make my last question to be more specific, here is my last question:
[IOS:CS193p fall2013 assignment2 task2:add a button to let user to restart the game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937453/ioscs193p-fall2013-assignment2-task2add-a-button-to-let-user-to-restart-the-ga)

This is the specific error message I got:
2014-07-26 10:31:55.110 Matchismo[525:60b] -[CardGameViewController redealButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c27590
2014-07-26 10:31:55.247 Matchismo[525:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CardGameViewController redealButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c27590'

Here is the code I wrote in the button touching method, trying to "clear" the original object(memory) which is referenced by my two properties(game, theDeck), and reassign them with brand new objects in order to restart the game.

```
- (IBAction)touchReadealButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    self.theDeck = [[PlayingCardDeck alloc] init];
    self.game = [[CardMatchingGame alloc]initWithCount:[self.cardButtons count] usingDeck:self.theDeck];
}
```

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to diagnose your problem. What is redealButton? Show any place you are using redealButton in your code.

Comment: Don't post another question. Update your previous one.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your button is hooked up to a `IBAction` method that does not exist anymore. Check the xib/storyboard where your `CardGameViewController` exists and check what the button is connected to. I'm guessing you renamed the method from `redealButton`: to `touchReadealButton`: at some point